# How to track number of events per unique user on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have an application that tracks the event where a user marks a 'post' as a favorite. In Google Analytics, I can see how many times the favorite-event has been triggered, and I can find out how many unique users have triggered it. Let's say 2000 favorite-events were triggered, and 1000 unique users triggered them. That would mean an average of 2 favorites per user.

I want to track/see how many favorite-events were actually triggered by the unique users, and group them by the number.
Let's say that 2 of the users have triggered 50 favorite-events each, and the rest has 1 or 2 favorites.

I need a list to see those numbers, for example like this:

```
[2 users]    [favorited] [50 times]
[1000 users] [favorited] [1 time]
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to use custom variables and/or dimensions?

Comment: Hi @Sti did you managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

GA Login> Behavior > Events > By Default It's shows total Events > Click Upon Drop Down > Select Unique Events    (Plz Refer Attached Screen Shots)
[image]
Then Filtered with your Goals as configured.

Comment: Yes, but can I here see how many times EACH USER has done it? I only find out how many unique users have done it at least once. I want to know "how many users did this action 3 times" "how many did it 40", "how many did it 1" ?